# Is it safe to update ubuntu over public Wifi?

Tags: updates, security

Is it safe to install ubuntu updates over public Wifi?

Does ubuntu make sure that fake updates don't get installed.

Is it possible that some updates can be compromised?

Answer (score 5):

Should be safe yes. As all packages are signed by the maintainers of the repository you are downloading from, which should prevent the files being tampered with.

If you want to be extra safe you can use HTTPS for downloading packages, with `apt-transport-https`.

Comment: This answer is misleading. Signatures are used to check for tampered files, they don't prevent it. HTTPS does not add any additional security on top of signature based checks, which cannot be bypassed without specific local modication to your system.

Answer (score 3):

From [whydoesaptnotusehttps.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20200326020753/https://whydoesaptnotusehttps.com/)

> Files obtained by APT are accompanied by their own signature which
> allows your system to check they originated from your distribution.
>
> These signatures are checked against a small set of trusted keys
> already stored on your computer. Downloaded files are rejected by APT
> if they are signed by an unknown key1 or are missing valid signatures.
> This ensures that the packages you are installing were authorised by
> your distribution and have not been modified or replaced since.

**Using HTTPS does not add any additional security (as any changes to the packages would fail signature checks), only a potential privacy improvement**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe but it is recommended to use VPN services while working on a public WiFi network. There are many free VPN services such as hide.me VPN, ProtonVPN.